# How to classify objects from a description in natural language

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp

My objective is to classify objects that all belong to a certain category, based on a textual description of these objects by humans. My problem is not specific to a certain category of objects, but for sake of clarity I am going to give examples as if the objects I wanted to classify were movies.

To be precise:

- the description contains both a judgement of the object, and a more objective description of the various parts of the object. For example: “*This movie has great lines, and the scenario is well-though. It counterbalances the poor actor performance. Still, overall I think it's a very good movie*”. This both contains information about different aspects of the movie, and provides a subjective review.
- what I want is:

  1. a score for each object (like a movie rating), based on how appreciated it is;
  2. for a given object, "similar" objects (ie. if you liked this movie, you might also enjoy these), based on similar "features" each object has. For instance, a movie which was also well-written might be considered "similar" to the former example.
- I also have access to a pre-existing classification of these objects. For instance, a movie might be labeled "action/thriller". This classification is too broad for my purposes (ie. not all "action/thriller" movies are similar), but it might be a good start.

I have though that to solve my problem, I could use sentiment analysis to give each object a score, and that natural language processing coupled with a feature space could do the trick for classifying objects.

The point is that I am unsure on how to proceed, because I am new to machine learning, natural language processing, and data sciences in general. I have nonetheless a CS and mathematical background.

**Could you provide some insight on where to start?** Are there libraries that already provide this kind of features?

*This is a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521152/how-to-classify-objects-from-a-description-in-natural-language), since it was not focused enough, and this forum seems more appropriate. It has been rewritten.*

Comment: Search for 'Huggingface transformers' for a package that already does a lot of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text vectorisation is a good way to have a reliable classification.

You have several libraries like doc2vec that you can use together with logistic regression or dimensional reduction technique like tSNE or UMAP.
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html

On the other hand, you can also use libraries like BERT or TF-IDF:

https://pypi.org/project/bert-document-classification/

https://medium.com/swlh/text-classification-using-tf-idf-7404e75565b8

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but could you please provide a bit more details please, I am really a newbie in statistical and data science techniques. Also, I'll wait a bit to see if there are other leads proposed, if not I'll probably accept your answer.

Comment: Also, I would like some details about how to get data to train models, if required, because some of the articles you mentioned require having a dataset that is already labeled, and it is not my case.

Comment: I can't explain you every solution in detail, first because I don't know them all completely. All I can say as an intuition starting point, is that you need to transform your text data into probabilistic vectors, i.e. a matrix where words proximity are compared to each other. For instance "Cup" is 70% related to "tea" and 60% related to "coffee", but 0.5% to "dinosaur", etc. This is done through the learning process. Doc contents are processed the same way. Then you can classify them with many different techniques. Here is one quite well explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvsE8jm1GzE

Comment: Indeed, that is broadly what I though of too (I explained it in more details in the other post, but it was quite long and tedious). The problem is I don't really know how to do that in practice.

Comment: In that case, my best recommendation is to start by a simple recommendation system using the predifined labels and extraction of key words from text (using NLTK) that you can evaluate with a basic sentiment analysis score, and then classify with a dimensional reduction technique or a logistic regression. Then increase complexity with text vectorisation/BERT/IDF.